# jsoup how to reach dropdownlist

Tags: java, android, json, jsoup

Hello everybody I want to get the data from 
http://sansoyunlari.hurriyet.com.tr/SayisalLoto/SayisalLotoSonuclari.aspx this adress by using jsoup ı can get them but only the latest results . There is a dropdownlist on the website which consists dates how can I reach other dates ? by the way I will move these codes to the android these are codes which is written in netbeans for now. ı will put a dropdownlist to my android program which get the data from this adress and also the results.

these are my java codes I wrote until now

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String adres = "http://sansoyunlari.hurriyet.com.tr/SayisalLoto/SayisalLotoSonuclari.aspx";
        ArrayList sayi = new ArrayList<>();
        sayi.add("six");
        sayi.add("five");
        sayi.add("four");
        sayi.add("three");
        sayi.add("two");
        sayi.add("one");
        //Sayısal Loto
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(adres).get();

            Elements sonuclar = doc.select("div.hurriyet2010_so_sanstopu_no_bg");

            //1. yi manuel almak gerek ilk yoldan çünkü resut diye kodlanmış
            Elements sonuclar1 = doc.select("span#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblresut"+sayi.get(sayi.size()-1));
            Element numaralar = sonuclar1.first();
            System.out.println(numaralar.text());

            //yol 1 numaraları almak için
            for (int i = sonuclar.size();i>1;i--)
            {
                sonuclar1 = doc.select("span#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblresult"+sayi.get(i-2));
                Element numaralar1 = sonuclar1.first();
                System.out.println(numaralar1.text());
            }

            //yol 2 numaraları almak için
            // for(Element el : sonuclar)
            // {
            // System.out.println(el.text());
            // }

            //kazanan kişi sayısı ve ikramiye tutarı için
            for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)
            {
                int b = 6 -i;
                System.out.println(b + " bilen kişi sayısı :");
                sonuclar = doc.select("span#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblluckycount"+sayi.get(i));
                Element el = sonuclar.first();
                System.out.println(el.text());

                System.out.println("Kişi başına düşen ikramiye :");
                sonuclar = doc.select("span#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblluckyamount"+sayi.get(i));
                el = sonuclar.first();
                System.out.println(el.text());

            }

         }
         catch(Exception e){

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the select item you should do:

```
Element select = doc.select("#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSayisalLotoDates").first();
```

Now the children of this elements are the "option" items you want:

```
for (Element e : select) {
    String date = e.text();
}
```

### edit

I looked at the html source. In order to get the right page you need to do a post request at the URL "http://sansoyunlari.hurriyet.com.tr/SayisalLoto/SayisalLotoSonuclari.aspx" with following params:

- __EVENTARGUMENT = *empty*
- __EVENTTARGET = _*ctl0$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSayisalLotoDates*
- __EVENTVALIDATION = *a random value that you get from the html page*
- __LASTFOCUS = *empty*
- __VIEWSTATE = *another random value*
- _ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:ddlSayisalLotoDates = *The ID of the date you want to search (i.e. **884** for **19 Ekim 2013**)*
- txtSearch = *can be empty*

As you can see, it's quite annoying scraping an ASP.NET webpage..

Comment: thanks for your answer but this was not what I meant. I know how to get the dates but I need when I chose a date on my program I need the results of that date

Comment: well you should do a post request to 'SayisalLotoSonuclari.aspx' page, with a POST body..you should investigate the html code to discover the values of that body

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856811/jsoup-post-dropdownlist I tried these codes but didn't work could you please look at them?

Comment: I had figured it out before I slept yesterday and I will write the answer here but you did it before me thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Use an application like Fiddler (or another one) to find the params you need to post (hidden inputs, session cookies, your selected input). Probably you're missing some of them.

Hope it helps.